# How can I calculate the initial velocity of a cue ball after hitting it with a cue stick?

Tags: collision-resolution, billiards

I'm currently building a billiard game, and I'm faced with the following problem:

[image]

A cue ball is hit with a stick at an angle equal to Θ. Given that the stick is hit at the exact center of the ball, and that the force behind the stick is equal to `X`, how do I calculate the initial `velocityX` and the `velocityY` of the cue ball?

I don't have the necessary physics education on this topic, so I'm seeking help from others using online resources like this forum, so I hope you understand my situation.

Comment: How long has the cue been accelerating with the force X, and what is its mass? We'll need those terms to calculate its momentum at the time of impact.

Comment: Can't you just give the ball the same velocity as the cue?  Presumably the user sets the strength of shot, you could pre-set a range of force 0-100, tweak it to feel right, and map that directly to the user input.